# Unable to access library store inside another react application

Tags: reactjs, redux, single-page-application

We have a react library with its own store where the authenticated token is available. Now when i try to use library store i'm getting the below error when adding the store to the provider

Here store is from react library
ex:

```
import store from 'example-library'
<Provider store={store}>
   <Router {...props}>
     <AppContainer />
         <Route path="/example" component={example} /> 
   </Router>
  </Provider>
```

Provider.js:25 Uncaught TypeError: store.getState is not a function

This is my library store

```
import { createStore, compose } from 'redux';
import rootReducer from './reducers'
const composeEnhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;
const initialState = {}

const store= createStore(
  rootReducer,
  initialState,
  composeEnhancers()
)


export default store;
```

Do I need to specify explicitly in webpack configuration to export the store? Anyways there is no compiler issue in the import statement

Comment: What does `console.log(store);` show when you use it in your consuming library? Is it defined? Are both using the same version of Redux? Also, is this a mono repo like with lerna or are you using npm/yarn link? I've had issues consuming my own libraries with the latter.

Comment: @zero298 Console log is giving me undefined when consuming the library and printing it.Both are same version of Redux. I'm using the npm one for library (webpack built)  Am I missing anything here please because of npm library

Comment: @zero298 want to check what is missing from my end. Since you already faced the same kind of issues.

Comment: @ https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/691711/zero298  I understand you have faced the same issue and want to check whether there is any quick solution as i'm unable to export a store in library and use it with other react apps with application store. I also understand storing in local storage is not a valid answer for this

Comment: I don't think I had the same issue you are having.  An export being undefined, to me, sounds like it is not being exported properly.  The issue that  I was speaking of was caused by mismatched React versions and webpack bundling too much together.  I don't think we have the same issue.

Comment: @ https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/691711/zero298  Thank you for the response. I'm able to export the store if i mention like this in webpack but when i access it now it is not undefined but seeing the initial state not the updated one. do we need to dispatch and try again or do we need to pass the store to some method and access the data which is not the right approach i guess.                                                                            >  entry:{
      index:[ 'regenerator-runtime/runtime.js','./src/App.js'],
      store: './src/store.js'